# Best practices for allowed values for a rest api

Tags: api, rest, post

I'm implementing a REST API where when adding a resource, certain POST fields can only have specific values. For example, I have a user resource with a usertype field: this usertype field can only have 2 values namely, administrator and user.

How do you allow developers to discover these allowed values in a RESTful manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define the concept of an enumeration in you media-type. You can then enumerate the allowable values in the hypermedia control that tells them where an what to post. For instance GETting `/users` might return the following:

```
<users href="/users">
    ... collection information and other controls you want to include ...
    <create href="/users" method="post">
        ... fields ...
        <usertype type="enum" cardinality="required">
            <administrator/>
            <user/>
        </usertype>
    </create>
</users>
```

The `create` element is a form, the `usertype` element is a form field and `administrator` and `user` are valid values for the enumeration. Based on this example, the structure of collections, forms, form fields and enumerations would be required in your media-type.

This is actually on of the things I love about REST. Because this information is communicated in-band, you can change it easily without breaking (well written) clients. For instance, just say you wanted to add `editor` to the enumeration, you can just add it. Old clients can just ignore it and new clients can take advantage of it. What's even nicer is that you can change the valid values based on the requestors authorisation. e.g. if the requestor is an administrator then they are given both `administrator` and `user` as valid values. If the requestor is a `user` then they are only given `user` as a valid option. Noice!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be a read-only resource /usertypes which returns the allowed values.